# Protractor - extremely strange behavior of framework in particular case

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

This is my spec:

```
var UsersPage = require('../pages/users_page.js');
var UserDetailsPage = require('../pages/user_details_page.js');
var WelcomePage = require('../pages/welcome_page.js');
var LogIn = require('../helper.methods/authentication');

describe('Test -> test', function () {

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var WAIT_TIMEOUT = 10000;

    beforeEach(function () {
        LogIn.asAdmin();
        var welcomePage = new WelcomePage();
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(welcomePage.usersButton), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'users tab did not become clickable');
        clickWithWait(welcomePage.usersButton);
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        var welcomePage = new WelcomePage();
        clickWithWait(welcomePage.loginButton);
        clickWithWait(welcomePage.logoutButton);
    });

    function expectVisibilityOf(element, message) {
        return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), WAIT_TIMEOUT, message);
    }

    it('verifies login validation and log in by newly added account', function () {
        var userDetailsPage = new UserDetailsPage();
        var usersPage = new UsersPage();
        expectVisibilityOf(usersPage.firstRow, 'element firstRow was not visible ');
        clickWithWait(usersPage.testUser);
        clickWithWait(userDetailsPage.addAccountButton);
        dv.sleep(500);
        clickWithWait(userDetailsPage.chooseDomainButton);
        clickWithWait(userDetailsPage.firstAvailableDomainFromList);
        clickWithWait(userDetailsPage.loginInputField);
        expectVisibilityOf(userDetailsPage.userLoginOfFirstAccount, 'element userLoginOfFirstAccount was not visible ');
        var busyLogin = userDetailsPage.userLoginOfFirstAccount.getText();
        setValueOfElement(userDetailsPage.loginInputField, Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));
        browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(userDetailsPage.loginLabelElement, 'Login is too short'), 5000, 'element loginLabelElement not contain: Login is too short');
        userDetailsPage.loginInputField.clear();
        setValueOfElement(userDetailsPage.loginInputField, busyLogin);
        browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(userDetailsPage.loginLabelElement, 'Login is already taken'), 5000, 'element loginLabelElement not contain: Login is already taken');
        userDetailsPage.loginInputField.clear();
        var userLogin = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 20);
        setValueOfElement(userDetailsPage.loginInputField, userLogin);
        browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(userDetailsPage.loginLabelElement, 'Login is available'), 5000, 'element loginLabelElement not contain: Login is available');
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(userDetailsPage.saveAccountButton), WAIT_TIMEOUT, 'element saveAccountButton was not clickable ');
        clickWithWait(userDetailsPage.saveAccountButton);
               });
```

Problem is very strange cause test flow works fine on my colleague computer (with Linux) but on mine (Mac OS) even did not start (just `beforeEach` and `afterEach` are performed). I am running this in Chrome, debugging in Intellij.
Tried to Invalidate/Restart cache in Intellij, restarting computer etc. but it did not help. I think that it could be some issue with compiler cause either locally on selenium grid problem is the same.

Moreover - what is the most interesting - when I've deleted the last line of test (`clickWithWait(userDetailsPage.saveAccountButton);`) then the test flow is going fine !

It's blowing my brain cause nobody has idea what is going on. Could anyone advise anything ?

In quick shortcut (once again) - the test works fine with line `clickWithWait(userDetailsPage.saveAccountButton);` commented  but  after uncomment (imo) only `BeforeEach` and `AfterEach` are done without even click on `usersPage.testuser` element.

Function `clickOnElementWithWait` is implemented like following (it was necessary to use it to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException`):

```
clickOnElementWithWait = function (element, attempts) {
    if (attempts == null) {
        attempts = 10;
    }
    return element.click().then(function (found) {
    }, function (err) {
        if (attempts > 0) {
            browser.sleep(100);
            return exports.clickOnElementWithWait(element, attempts - 1);
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    });
};
```

Function `setValueOfElement` is implemented like following (it was necessary as well to use it to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException`):

```
setValueOfElement = function (element, value, attempts) {
    if (attempts == null) {
        attempts = 10;
    }
    return element.sendKeys(value).then(function (found) {
    }, function (err) {
        if (attempts > 0) {
            browser.sleep(100);
            return exports.setValueOfElement(element, attempts - 1);
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Are `clickWithWait` and `clickOnElementWithWait` different in implementation? Or they both are same?

Comment: @GirishSortur  `clickWithWait` is the global of `clickOnElementWithWait` - it's is the same. `onPrepare: function () { var helpers =` `require('../e2e/protractor/helper.methods/helpers.js'); global.clickWithWait` `= helpers.clickOnElementWithWait;`